# object is in db - but i am still getting 500 - django

Tags: python, django

I am getting 500 Error even if the object is in db. The Error is:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

error line is:

```
    location = Location.objects.get(id=lid)                
    return render_to_response('location.html',{'location':location},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this is the whole view function:

```
def location(request,locname,lid):
    try: 
       location = Location.objects.get(id=lid)                
       return render_to_response('location.html',{'location':location},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    except Location.DoesNotExist:     
       return render_to_response('404.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this is the error traceback: http://pastebin.com/v0ACzRBj

what am i doing wrong? The thing is that other locations in same form are fine. I can open their profile, but only two locations profiles are giving 500 error.

Comment: 500 is just a server error. It may have another issue in the code. I don't think this can be debugged on just this code. May need to see more.

Comment: Can you add a bit more details? That's not a problem with your database query, you'd get a Location.DoesNotExist if it didn't exist.

Comment: Maybe show your entire view function.

Comment: @all, ok i will post the whole view function

Comment: Post the template, there is an issue in your template. You are passing an empty string to `|random` filter.

Comment: Seems you have an error in a template with variable passed to `random` filter

Comment: @kroolik, u saved my life man, absolutely i forgot the old code ``random`` to delete. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to learn to read the error traceback. It is quite clear that the error is coming from a call to the `|random` template filter. Perhaps you are passing an empty value.

Comment: absolutely! great! i forgot this old code :(. yeaah, i am a bit bad at reading error tracebacks.